# Broken Foursquare like animate feed

Tags: javascript, jquery

HI,

For some reason, the function 'shift()' is not being defined properly according to the firebug console tab.  I took this directly from a tutorial, not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
//animate post feed cycle
 var delay = 2000; // you can change it
  var count = 3; // How much items to animate
  var showing = 2; //How much items to show at a time
  var i = 0;
  function move(i) {
    return function() {
      $('.feed'+i).remove().css('display', 'none').prependTo('#recent_listings');
    }
  }
  function shift() {
    var toShow = (i + showing) % count;
    $('.feed'+toShow).slideDown(1000, move(i));
    $('.feed'+i).slideUp(1000, move(i));
    i = (i + 1) % count;
    setTimeout('shift()', delay);
  }    

 setTimeout('shift()', delay);
```

The markup looks like this (the double brackets are django context variables)

```
    <div id="recent_listings">
    <h2>Recent Listings</h2>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="entries feed{{forloop.counter}}">
        <a href="{{post.get_absolute_url}}">
        <div class="photo">
        <img src="{{site}}media/no-image.png"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="listings">
            <div class="title">
            <h3>{{post.title|truncatewords:5}}</h3>
             </div>
       </div>
           </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you provide some of the markup used for this? maybe put it in a jsfiddle example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you are not closing your a tag (not really the issue but will probably cause other issues later)

Secondly it looks like it could be a js context issue. You might want to declare your function as a public function to do this change the shift declaration to the bellow

```
this.shift = function() {
    //code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks d1k_is, you answer was spot on.  I made the function a global variable and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on the answer of @d1k_is:

You shouldn't call `setTimeout` with a string. The string is most likely not being evaluated in the context you need. That's why d1k_is suggests defining the function in the global context. However it would be better to use a reference to the function called:

```
setTimeout(shift, delay);
```

BTW, since you are "recursively" calling `setTimeout` you may want to use `setInterval` instead.

Comment: Hi Roto, is there a huge performance edge to using SetInterval as opposed to the recursive method?

Comment: No. It's just the more sensible choice.